# Method or tool to alter reported free disk space for software installation test

Tags: manual-testing, tools

I'm looking for a suitable tool or method that will allow me to alter the reported free disk drive space. This is in order to ensure that software installation correctly fails if minimum free HDD space is not available.

My environment for this test is strictly Windows based Vista through to 8.1, both 32 and 64 bit versions. Some of the test environments are VM's and others dedicated test boxes. The software installer uses WiX toolset.

I have looked into configuring VM's with tiny virtual drives to provide a similar result but ideally would require a tool that can be run within OS that would provide flexibility to alter the reported space on the fly.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you search for this? Googling for "fill windows disk" I found for example http://blog.edgoad.com/2010/08/quickly-create-blank-file-to-fill-disk.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528567/how-can-i-simulate-a-disk-full-error-in-a-windows-environment which provide couple suggestions like creating ramdisk, or filling the disk with fsutil.

Comment: Nice one thanks Edu. I was using much more flowery search terms - thanks for the straight forward answer and links.

Comment: I used the fsutil method as described in Edu's second link. Simple and effective - thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Writing this answer on behalf of the OP, who answered the question in a comment.)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528567/how-can-i-simulate-a-disk-full-error-in-a-windows-environment describes multiple methods for filling the entire disk.